# How can i integrate jquery auto slider with next previous button

Tags: asp.net, jquery

1. In my asp.net application i need to integrate a jquery content slider with next, previous buttons.
   2.Please look at the snap shot given below.
   [alt text http://208.109.217.57:1082/homestaging/Contentslider.bmp](http://208.109.217.57:1082/homestaging/Contentslider.bmp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few plugins that does this kind of stuff. You can try [this](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/) for example. If it doesn't fit you can just [google](http://www.google.se/#hl=sv&q=jquery+slideshow&meta=&aq=f&oq=jquery+slideshow&fp=e075e3c5aacffd00) it and you'll find a lot of plugins.